# How to use if statements in kivy lang

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I want to make a widget that only displays if a certain condition is met. I have tried it in the kv lang file, tho I don't know how to do it properly. When using a conditional I get a syntax error.

the error I get: "Invalid class name"
I know that there should be a class, tho how else can it be done?

this is what I tried to do (I have simplified the code)

main.py

```
class Game(Screen):
    condition = BooleanProperty(True)
```

main.kv

```
Game:
    FloatLayout:
        if condition:
            SomeWidget:
```

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/41201276/2308683

Comment: Have a look at kivy [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#valid-expressions).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
Game:
    FloatLayout:
        SomeWidget:
            pos: (-self.width, -self.height) if self.condition else (0, 0)
```

Of course, you can do that with any `Property` (`size_hint`, `opacity`, `pos`, ...)